# Noetherian and Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, noetherian

A Noetherian space satisfies that any non-empty set of open subsets must have a maximal element. But a Hausdorff space satisfies that, for $x\neq y$ two different points, there exists open neighborhoods $U,V$ containing $x,y$ respectively such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

My question is: when we consider the set of open subsets
$$\{U,V\}$$
there is no maximal element in this set. So how can a Noetherian space be Hausdorff too? Thank you!

Comment: Easiest example are finite sets with the discrete topology. Those are both noetherian and Hausdorff.

Comment: And finite discrete spaces are in fact the only examples of Noetherian Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually both $U$ and $V$ are maximal elements of $\{U,V\}$. It seems you’re confusing maximal elements with greatest elements. If we have a partially ordered set $(X,\leq)$, then an element $x$ is called a greatest element if we have $y\leq x$ for all $y$. It is called a maximal element if for all $y$, we have that $x\leq y$ implies $y=x$. The characterization of Noetherian spaces that you mention talks about *maximal* elements, not *greatest* elements.

Comment: Ah! It is such a trivial confusion. Thank you!